# How to find out F5 platform type via CLI?

Tags: f5

There are a few platform in CLI such as:

1. BIG-IP 2000
2. BIG-IP 4000
3. BIG-IP 3600
4. BIG-IP 1600

Reference: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K53183580

My question is how to identify which platform is running on F5 via command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`# show sys hardware` will display you all the information you're looking for

As example:

```
...
Platform
  Name  BIG-IP i2600
...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to view it through the webUI. Device Management > Devices > select the device > then look for "Platform Name" ie: i2600